# Printing excel files that match cell, but first file doesnt print

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that runs through the filenames in col B and if it finds a text string that matches a file from a directory then it will export it as a pdf.

For some reason the the loop doesn't print the first file in the list. When i step thru then they all print.

Does anyone see anything in my code that could solve this problem?

Thanks

EDIT: problem was that enabling the `PrintCommunication` was making the first sheet fail. `PrintCommunication` is needed off tho so the PageSetup works as needed.

Code is updated below for anyone to use. All you would have to change is the MyFolder location or use `With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)` to pick the folder.

```
Sub ExcelPrint()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim OpenFile As Variant
Dim MyFile As String, MyFolder As String, AorB As String
Dim sourceFolder As String, destFolder As String
Dim LR As Long

MyFolder = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Value
LR = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
sourceFolder = Environ("Userprofile") & "\Desktop\PDF\"
destFolder = sourceFolder & "_Temp\"

If Len(Dir(sourceFolder, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
    MkDir sourceFolder
End If

If Len(Dir(destFolder, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
    MkDir destFolder
End If

On Error GoTo eHandler    
With Worksheets("Print")
For i = 3 To LR
    MyFile = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2)
    AorB = Mid(Cells(i, 2), 4, 1)
    OpenFile = MyFolder & MyFile & ".xlsx"
    Application.StatusBar = "Printing " & MyFile & ".xlsx"

    Workbooks.Open _
            FileName:=OpenFile, _
            ReadOnly:=True

    Application.PrintCommunication = False
        With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
            .Orientation = xlLandscape
            .FitToPagesTall = 1
            .FitToPagesWide = 1
            If AorB = "A" Then
                .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
            ElseIf AorB = "B" Then
                .PaperSize = xlPaperTabloid
            End If
        End With
'This was the problem        
'Application.PrintCommunication = True

    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        FileName:=destFolder & MyFile & ".pdf", _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        From:=1, To:=1, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=True
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    Application.StatusBar = vbNullString

    'Green Highlight if printed
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Print")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        If Not Dir(destFolder & MyFile & ".pdf", vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then
            Sheets("Print").Cells(i, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 10
            Sheets("Print").Cells(i, 2).Font.Color = vbWhite
        End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

nextLine:
Next i
End With
Exit Sub

eHandler:
If err.Number = 1004 Then
    Resume nextLine
ElseIf err.Number = 424 Then
    Resume nextLine
ElseIf err.Number = 9 Then
    Resume nextLine
End If

MsgBox err.Number & vbCrLf & err.Description
Application.StatusBar = vbNullString
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the first document name in B3 ? or is it in B2? You loop from `i = 3 to LR` Just verifying this isn't the issue.

Comment: my range of files are always after row 2. In this case the first excel file is in row 7. rows 3 - 6 are autocad files that the script is pulling the 1004 error which i tell it to resume nextline to continue

Comment: When you run it does it not print any of the files or does it just skip the fist 'valid' file?

Comment: it skips the first valid file, prints the other perfectly then when it finished the first file is just sitting there in the background

Comment: Have you tried changing which file is first to ensure it is a problem with that line and not the filename?

Comment: yes i have tried other sets of filenames and it seems to always be the first one

Comment: There are only two other possible things that I can think of: 1. Is printing and not turning the cell green?(Could be a timing issue). 2. Maybe something about your `With Worksheets("Print")` on the outside of your loop is having issues since you also reference `ActiveSheet`.